# What is the motivation behind Radon measures?

Tags: measure-theory

I am struggling to see the motivation behind Radon measures. In many places I see that they are described as measures that "interact nicely with the underlying topology", but without further elaboration. On Wikipedia it states

> A common problem is to find a good notion of a measure on a topological space that is compatible with the topology in some sense. One way to do this is to define a measure on the Borel sets of the topological space. In general there are several problems with this: for example, such a measure may not have a well defined support.

Yet they go on do define a Radon measure as being defined on Borel sets so how does that solve the problem they mentioned? What is the usefulness of Radon measures and why are they defined as they are?

Comment: In those "many places" you surely saw Radon measures used for something... What other measures you would prefer to use to do all that?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I do not have much experience with them aside from Radon measures being identified with positive linear functionals on $C_c(X)$. I suppose what's been confusing me is what do Radon measures do that Borel measures don't? Where do the latter fall short?